# .PST Vanishing from Drive after Windows Update

Tags: outlook

Alright, so here’s the situation:

First, I’ve implemented a WSUS server and GPO to prevent/keep and centrally managed our windows update systems and the only updates I push out automatically are Critical updates, service packs, and Security Essentials definition updates. These take place at 8:00pm nightly with the exception of MSE which happens every hour if they are available.

This morning 2 of our managers, one is customer service the other accounting, and one of our sales reps, came in to find their POP3 outlook 2010 PST files gone. Just completely not there. Because we use folder redirection, all PST files are stored in appdata\local\microsoft\outlook in the local user profile (no roaming profiles just redirection at this point).  I took an image of the accounting machine using FTK imager and the location of the PST is there and the file is there.  Curiously, the 2 archive files are recoverable and working after an export. However, the main pst that was 5.9 GB was reading 0 bytes.  I took 2 more images and all report the same thing, that the main pst is 0 bytes. The last modified time was 8:17:41pm yesterday 8/14/2012.

I started the imaging on the other two machines and will know more about those tomorrow.

All folder redirections and GPO according the event log pushed out successfully.  Several of the KB updates (I forgot to bring them home), totaling 5, had to do with Office Home and Business 2010 Single Point Image (according the event log). It pushed out to all 35 machines successfully without 3 machines having this outlook issue.  Two of these machines were infected with a Maclicioustool:win64/spector Trojan/virus back on 7/3 when MSE quarantined and deleted the file.

Any ideas on where to start so I can give my bosses an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas/thoughts. One, ensure antivirus agent on them is fully updated and functioning, then run a full, invasive scan, with every A/V option turned up, "full tilt boogie" to catch anything - but do it from a bootable CD so you aren't loading anything malicious from the OS.

I'm guessing the OS is Win7, which runs something called [Volume Shadow Copy](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_Volume_Shadow_Copy_on_Windows_Server_2008), which uses System Restore Point. At this point, pull up the VSC history, and I'll bet that's where your original .PST's are located.

Also, I trust the version of Office is 2007 or higher. 5.9 GB PST is way too large for Outlook 2003 and would likely be corrupted. And folder redirection to a local folder on the host has nothing to do with files disappearing, but you probably already knew that. :)